# Multiple Thread JUnit Test with ServerSockets and Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write a JUnit test for a server/client I wrote, so I created Runnable that acts as a server and my current thread acts as a client. I call start() on the server Runnable before attempting to write to the client socket's output stream. However, my program always terminates after `Socket client = new Socket("hostname", 0);` and I'm not sure why. My guess is that it's because I'm trying to create both a socket and client in the same test? Hence, binding an ip as a client and listening to that ip at the same time which causes an irregular behavior? Is this correct? How do I fix this dilemma?

```
public void test() {
        int result;
        String strMsg = "dasda";
        try {
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ServerRunnable());
            serverThread.start();
            Socket client = new Socket("hostname", 0);
            OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
            os.write(strMsg.getBytes());
            InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
            while (true){
                result = is.read();
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
                bb.putInt(result);
                String input = new String(bb.array());
                if (input=="Success") return;
            }
        } catch (IOException e1){
            fail("IOException on client");
        }

    }

    class ServerRunnable implements Runnable {
        ServerSocket server;
        public ServerRunnable(){
            server = new ServerSocket(0);
        }
        public void run(){
            try {
                active = true;
                    while (active) {
                     Socket sock = server.accept();
                    }
            } catch (IOException e1){
                fail("IOException in Server");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new ServerSocket(0)` will create a server that listens on any free port which will vary every time the test is run.  `new Socket("hostname", 0)` though is attempting to connect specifically to port 0 which will fail.

Since you are initializing the server first you can then call `getLocalPort()` on the `ServerSocket` to get the port that the server is listening on and then use this port number when creating the client `Socket`.

You likely will also need to change the host from `"hostname"` to `"localhost"` so that it will connect to the port on the local computer.

Below is an example adapted from your code.  The main item to look at is the `Socket client = new Socket("localhost", sr.getPort());`

```java
public void test() throws Exception {
    // start up the server
    ServerRunnable sr = new ServerRunnable();
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(sr);
    serverThread.start();

    // connect the client to the port the server is listening on
    Socket client = new Socket("localhost", sr.getPort());

    // client socket interactions go here

    client.close();
}

class ServerRunnable implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket server;

    public ServerRunnable() throws IOException {
        // listen on any free port
        server = new ServerSocket(0);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket sock = server.accept();

                // normally you will need to start a thread to handle
                // the new socket so that the server will be able to accept
                // new connections but this may not be necessary for
                // unit testing where only a single connection occurs.

                sock.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return server.getLocalPort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is very infomative. However, with my code above, I notice that whenever I create a socket with new Socket("localhost",0), I get an IOException. Is this because port 0 is possibly in use?